# Static generation and SWR in single page

Tags: javascript, next.js, swr

I'm building a blog website in Next.js, the API for the blog is from some headless CMS.

In a page I want to do the following:

1. List some blogs.
2. Set of buttons available, based on each button click different set of blogs are loading (should replace the blogs in #1).

Since SEO is needed I'm pretty confused to use which approach should I choose.

What I thinking that I generate the initial list with
`getStaticProps` (Static Generation), and after loading I want to replace the blogs based on user action (button click).

But I'm confused, is it possible to use static generation and SWR in single page?

Here is my implementation.

`pages/index.js`

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const resPosts  = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}posts?per_page=4&&_embed`)
    const posts = await resPosts.json()
    return {
        props: {
            posts
        },
        revalidate:10
      }
}

export default function Home({posts}) {
  return (
    <div> 
      //pass data to FeaturedBlogs component (Components/featuredBlogs.js)
      <FeaturedBlogs categories={categories} posts={posts} />
    </div>
  )    
}
```

`Components/featuredBlogs.js`

```js
const FeaturedBlogs = ({posts }) => {            
    return (
        <div className={`${blogStyles.feature_blogs_wrap}`}>
            //need to load the below blogs based on button click
            <button onClick={handleClick('health')}>Health</button>
            <button onClick={handleClick('latest')}>Latest</button>
            //listing blogs
            {posts.map((item ) => ( 
                <Link  key={item.id} href="/blog/view" passHref={true}>
                    <section>
                        <Image alt="blog_img" src={item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url} width="200" height="200" />
                        <div className={`${blogStyles.feature_blogs_content}`}>
                            <div className={`${blogStyles.feature_blogs_label}`}>
                                <span>{item._embedded['wp:term'][0][0].name}</span>
                            </div>
                            <p>{item.title.rendered}</p>
                            <div className={`${blogStyles.feature_blogs_author}`}>
                                <Image alt="author" src={item._embedded.author[0].avatar_urls[48]}  width="200" height="200" />
                                <span>{item._embedded.author[0].name}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
            
const handleClick = (id) =>  {
    //console.log(id)  
}
```

What I need is to load the blogs in  `handleClick` event, but the problem is this will not work since it's generated from the server at build time.

Comment: _"is it possible to use static generation and SWR in single page"_  - Yes, that's possible to do. Are you having any specific issue with the implementation? I'd recommend a read through [SWR  Usage with Next.js](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs).

Comment: I have some issues with the implementation could you please have a look @juliomalves

Comment: Are you able to fetch posts from a specific category from the API?

Comment: Yeah that's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `FeaturedBlogs` component, you can create a state variable to keep track when a new category is selected on the client-side.

```js
const [category, setCategory] = useState()
```

You can then make `useSWR` conditionally fetch data based on the value of this `category` variable.

```js
const { data, loading } = useSWR(category ? [category] : null, fetcher)
```

The `fetcher` function would have the logic to fetch the posts for a given category.

```js
const fetcher = async (category) => {
    const response = await fetch(/* Endpoint to get posts for given category */)
    return await response.json()
}
```

With this in place, you can have the component render the `posts` retrieved in `getStaticProps` as a default, when `category` is not set. This would happen on the initial render of the page. However, when a button is clicked, and `category` gets set, that category's data will be fetched and rendered instead.

Here's the full code of a modified version of your original component.

```js
// Components/featuredBlogs.js

const fetcher = async (category) => {
    const response = await fetch(/* Endpoint to get posts for given category */)
    return await response.json()
}

const FeaturedBlogs = ({ posts }) => {
    // Add state variable to keep track of the selected category
    const [category, setCategory] = useState()
    // Fetch posts from category only if `category` is set
    const { data, loading } = useSWR(category ? [category] : null, fetcher)

    const handleClick = (cat) => () => {
        setCategory(cat)
    }
    
    // If `category` is set render data with post for given category, otherwise render all posts from `getStaticProps`
    const itemsToRender = category ? data : posts

    return (
        <div className={blogStyles.feature_blogs_wrap}>
            <button onClick={handleClick('health')}>Health</button>
            <button onClick={handleClick('latest')}>Latest</button>
            {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
            {!!itemsToRender?.length && itemsToRender.map((item) => (
                <!-- Render items here -->
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```